# How to omit merged rows in IF Statement CountA criteria?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a CASE statement that omits a block of columns, and then n IF statement that hides columns if worksheetfunction.COUNTA < 2. I pretty much just wanted to hide columns with only headers, and no values in the column. Thing is, there is a block of columns ("P:U") that have a merged overarching header in row 1, while the regular headers are in row 2, data starts on row 3.

I tried to adjust `Set R = Cells(1,i).EntireColumn` to `Set R = Cells(2,i).EntireColumn` so that way it'd only apply the IF statement from the 2nd row--down, but that's not working correctly. The statement still shows one column from columns P:U  because of the merged cells in row 1.

```
Option Explicit
    Sub ColumnHider()

        Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
        Dim i As Long, R As Range

        Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

        For i = 1 To 44

            Select Case i

            Case 9 To 14

            Case Else

                Set R = Cells(2, i).EntireColumn <---problem area

                If wf.CountA(R) < 2 Then R.Hidden = True

            End Select

        Next i

    End Sub
```

Comment: Using `EntireColumn` will select all the cells in the column, no matter the row you put.  Instead, adjust that to be a range, e.g. ` Set R = Range(Cells(2,2),Cells(lastRow,2))`

Comment: @BruceWayne I added that in, and now it's not hiding any columns

Comment: I'm not positive if it's affecting anything but I'd actually add *something* in the first `Case`, even just `debug.print "This is 9 to 14"`. I'll review the rest and get back to you.

Comment: Can you show an example of the column(s) that have a merged header?